# Why should I put if(have_posts()), is while(have_posts()) not enough?

Tags: loop

I have a question about "the loop".

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Code taken from [The Loop WordPress Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

Why should I put `if` part?
It seems like if there is `while` loop, works fine.

In what case problem occurs if there is no `if` statement?

### Edit

I accepted @Chip's answer. but honestly saying I need only last part.

I know now what I wanted to know from my question.

> `if` statement is only when necessary, if you want to put a header or footer that should be write only once. if you don't use the "wrapper", then `if` statement is not necessary.

Comment: I voted up before reading the_content, the_title is decisive!

Comment: Excellent (final) edit. Most people use the if and while directly after each other without ever using an else. Likely because of copy & paste.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The WordPress template loader will include the appropriate contextual template file in many circumstances, even if the query for that context returns no posts. For example:

- The Main Blog Posts Index
- Category Archive Index (Category exists, but has no posts)
- Tag Archive Index (Tag exists, but has no posts)
- Author Archive Index (Author exists, but has no posts)
- Search Results Index

Thus, in these cases, the appropriate template file will be loaded, but no posts will be output, because the query returns no posts.

Proof-of-concept examples:

- [Category exists, but has no posts](http://design.chipbennett.net/oenology/category/blogroll/) (category template included)
- [Category does not exist](http://design.chipbennett.net/oenology/category/sit-amet) (404 template included)

So, in these contexts, it is useful for the template file to include the `if ( have_posts() )` conditional.

In other contexts, the template file will never be loaded if the query returns no posts. For example:

- Single blog post
- Static page

In these contexts, `if ( have_posts() )` is probably unnecessary.

### Edit

> I understand the query is invoked by the_post(), right? And if while(have_posts()) exist, the query is never occurs if there is no post.

To understand what's going on, [you have to look at the order of WordPress actions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference). Starting with `wp_loaded` (and omitting some for clarity):

- `wp_loaded`
- `parse_request`
- `send_headers`
- `parse_query`
- `pre_get_posts`
- `wp`
- `template_redirect`
- `get_header`
- `wp_head`
- `the_post`
- `wp_footer`

So, what's happening, and in what order?

- The query is invoked:

  - `parse_query`
  - `pre_get_posts`
  - `wp`
- The template is selected:

  - `template_redirect`
- The template is loaded/output. The following actions are fired *by the template*:

  - `get_header`
  - `wp_head`
  - `the_post`
  - `dynamic_sidebar`
  - `get_footer`
  - `wp_footer`

So, `the_post`, fired by `the_post()`, happens *long after* the query is parsed, posts are fetched, and the template is loaded.

> I'm very grateful that you give a lot of information that I didn't know, but this is not what I asked.

Oh, but I believe that it is *exactly* what you asked.

The real question is: *what is a valid query return*? For contexts such as the category archive index, the query is valid, and the category template is loaded, if the queried category ID exists, *even if there are no posts assigned to that category*.

Why? Because the query being parsed is (IIRC) `&cat={ID}` - which is a valid query *even if there are no posts assigned to that category*, and thus doesn't result in a 404 upon parsing.

In that case, you get a valid query, and a template file loaded, *but no posts*. Thus, `if ( have_posts() )`, *is, in fact* relevant. Again, here is an example: [category exists, but has no posts assigned. Category template file is loaded, with `if ( have_posts() )` returning `false`](http://design.chipbennett.net/oenology/category/blogroll/).

This won't hold true for queries that include a *post* variable (`&p={ID}`) such as single blog posts and static pages, because the post won't actually exist, and when parsed, the query will not return a valid object.

### Edit 2

> If I rightly understand if there is no if(have_posts()) in a category template and the category have no post, then it return 404.php, even though it should be return category-sample.php without post. Is that right?

No. Remember: the template is selected at `template_redirect`. So if the query if valid, then the appropriate template file is loaded. If the query is not valid, then the 404 template is loaded.

So, once a template is loaded - e.g. the category template - once the loop is output, *the template does not change*.

Look again at the order of actions:

- `parse_query`
- `pre_get_posts`
- `wp`
- `template_redirect` - **template is chosen and loaded here.** This is the template *point of no return*. The template cannot change after this point.
- ...
- `the_post` - **postdata is setup here, as part of the loop call.** This is called *inside the template*, and *the template does not change* based on available data in the query object

### Final Edit

> And I'am claiming that while checks existence of posts, why should I run the same test twice. That is my question from first point I've been asking only about that.

And with that, I finally understand: all along, your question had nothing to do with *WordPress*, or the *WordPress Loop*. You're asking about wrapping any arbitrary PHP `while` loop inside an `if` conditional that checks the same condition.

That question is outside the scope of WPSE, but I'll briefly explain:

An `if` conditional is a binary evaluation: it's either `true` or `false`, and what happens *inside* of that conditional is executed *once*.

A `while` conditional is a *loop*: it remains true for some discrete period, based on some sort of counter; and what happens *inside* of that conditional is executed *several times* - once for *each iteration* of the counter.

So, let's say that you want to output an unordered list of things, if the list of things is populated. If you use a `while` loop, and omit the `if` wrapper, your markup would look like this:

```
<ul>
<?php while ( list_of_things() ) : ?>
    <li><?php the_list_item(); ?></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

And if `list_of_things()` was empty, the rendered output would be:

```
<ul>
</ul>
```

Which leaves unnecessary (and invalid) markup.

But if you add in an `if` conditional wrapper, you can do this:

```
<?php if ( list_of_things() ) : ?>
    <ul>
    <?php while ( list_of_things() ) : ?>
        <li><?php the_list_item(); ?></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And if `list_of_things()` was empty, no markup at all would be output.

That's just one example. There are lots of uses for that `if` conditional wrapper, and the `if` conditional wrapper serves an *entirely different purpose* than the `while` loop.

Comment: In my singular post/page templates, since a long time, I use only `the_post();` because also the `while` is unnecessary. +1 for the completeness of informations.

Comment: @G.M. Possibly removing the `if( have_posts() )` statement makes sense (that's what I am trying to find out), but [**don't just use `the_post()` in singular pages!**](http://themeshaper.com/2013/09/03/a-proper-loop/)

Comment: @ChipBennett All considered, do you think it is safe to remove the `if( have_post() )` condition before the full loop in the context of `single-*.php` and `page-*.php` template files?

Comment: "Safe" really has no definitive meaning in this context.

Answer (score 11):

It's really impossible to improve on Chip's answer, but just to cut to the chase:

Use the `if` part if you want to have something different show up when there are **no posts**. This is particularly useful, for example, on a date or category archive page. If someone navigates to a page that has no posts, it's nice to have a message that says so, rather than just nothing appearing at all, because the loop never gets executed.

```
if ( have_posts() ):
  // Yep, we have posts, so let's loop through them.
  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  // do your loop
  endwhile;
else :
  // No, we don't have any posts, so maybe we display a nice message
  echo "<p class='no-posts'>" . __( "Sorry, there are no posts at this time." ) . "</p>";
endif;
```

Comment: And this is all one needs to know.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some considerations that are not included in the answers so far. It is not recommended to omit the if statement.

**The if statement is commonly used to:**

- output something like `no posts found` to indicate that the category in question has no articles assigned to it.
- to decide if surrounding html ( like an ul ) should be output before and after the articles.

**What if a new hook is added?**

Another possible issue of not using the if statement is that if the wordpress team ever decided to add a new hook that triggers on the first `$wp_query->have_posts()` call, it would trigger at the wrong time. And if that causes unexpected behavior it would be your fault for not following the spec properly.

**Other devs expect to see a specific structure for the wordpress loop**

I suppose other developers expect to see the entire wordpress loop. So maybe it is a bad idea to have them searching for an if statement that isn't there.

Answer (score -1):

I see this as a fundamental question of control structure theory. The enclosed block within the while loop doesn't execute even once if condition (have_posts()) evaluates as false the first time.

So, the the purpose of `if ( have_posts() )` in the WordPress loop is only to execute the function have_posts() once before the while condition is evaluated. If `have_posts()` has no side-effects, then the `if ( have_posts() )` is totally pointless. If `have_posts()` does have side-effects, you could simplify as follows:

```
<?php have_posts(); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: That simplification is invalid PHP, you have an else statement that has no attached if statement. At best it's difficult to read

Comment: The `if` is there because of the `else` after it. No other reason. If there are no posts, then displaying a nice "no posts" message is better than displaying nothing.